# PHP/Codeigniter: How do I fetch the value of zero rather than NULL?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not sure how clear my question is? But let me explain further. Before a person answers the test the result should be hyphen (-), When the person answers the test and gets a score it should display the score he has received. Now that was all working fine. But I noticed that when I score 0 It still displays as hyphen (-) when it should display 0. I will post my code below:

CODE:

```
<?php 
 if($skillsets)
 foreach($skillsets as $skill => $percentage){ ?>
 <div class="skill_block">
     <div class="small"><?php echo $skill ?></div>
     <?php if($percentage === 0) { ?>
     <div class="big">0%</div>
     <?php } else if($percentage == NULL) { ?>
     <div class="big">-</div>
     <?php } else { ?>
     <div class="big"><?php echo $percentage ?>%</div>
     <?php } ?>
 </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

> 19/01/2016

**UPDATE:**

The type of `$percentage` is float

Comment: Is $percentage an int? Use triple = at NULL too. Otherwise it'll just be if ( 0 == 0)

Comment: @Abdulla That didn't work, it set all the values to 0

Comment: @JameyD Same as above, it sets all values to 0

Comment: there is simple method called is_null() which you can use :)

Comment: So do I need to call this on the `$percentage` variable when it should be (-) or when it should be 0?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're fetching these scores from a database ... when you do that, NULLs will be nulls, but integers will be string representations of numbers.
Hence, your first check fails because you actually have *string* '0' instead of integer `0`; then, as already pointed out by others - `== NULL` will match all "empty" values, such as NULL, FALSE, string '0', integer '0', etc.

You should do this:

```
<?php 
if($skillsets)
{
     foreach($skillsets as $skill => $percentage)
     {
         // isset() checks if a variable exists and is not null
         if (isset($percentage))
         {
             $percentage = $percentage.'%';
         }
         else
         {
             $percentage = '-';
         } ?>
         <div class="skill_block">
             <div class="small"><?php echo $skill; ?></div>
             <div class="big"><?php echo $percentage; ?></div>
         </div>
 <?php
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It is still fetching the values as 0%

Comment: That's what you asked for.

Comment: Only when the value is zero, The other values are still on NULL

Comment: With this code, it is *impossible* for a NULL value to be shown as 0% - if I were you, I'd check my values. Also, your question description says a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(!empty($skillsets)){ # added { in condition
    foreach($skillsets as $skill => $percentage)
    { ?>
         <div class="skill_block">
             <div class="small"><?php echo $skill ?></div>
             <?php 
             if($percentage == 0 || empty($percentage))  # Changed
             { 
                ?>
                <div class="big">0%</div>
                <?php 
             } 
             else { ?>
                 <div class="big"><?php echo $percentage ?>%</div>
                 <?php 
             } ?>
         </div>
     <?php 
    } 
}
else
{
    echo "skillsets is empty";
}
```

Comment: @davidnoronha check this changes

Comment: It has to show as hyphens when not answered. This changes all values to 0%

Comment: Wht is the values in there

Comment: No values set, Only if an exam is answered then values are set, Answered an Exam and got a score of zero, instead of displaying 0% it displays -

Comment: What is value in $percentage??

Comment: NULL, but some how 0 also acts the same as NULL, I guess the values when zero goes as NULL

Comment: Echo tht variabke and post ansr

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
<?php 
 if($skillsets){
 foreach($skillsets as $skill => $percentage){ ?>
 <div class="skill_block">
     <div class="small"><?php echo $skill ?></div>
     <?php if(!isset($percentage) || $percentage === NULL) { ?>
     <div class="big">-</div>
     <?php } else if($percentage == 0) { ?>
     <div class="big">0%</div>
     <?php } else { ?>
     <div class="big"><?php echo $percentage ?>%</div>
     <?php } ?>
 </div>
     <?php } 
 } ?>
```

Comment: Still displaying all as hyphens as 0's

Comment: Have changed the code as per what you have edited still the samething, I even tried keeping just `if(!isset($percentage))` still nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
<?
if($skillsets){
    foreach($skillsets as $skill => $percentage)
    { 
    ?>
        <div class="skill_block">
            <div class="small"><?php echo $skill ?></div>           
            <?php if(empty($percentage) || $percentage == NULL) { ?>
                <div class="big">-</div>
            <?php 
            } 
            else { ?>
                <div class="big"><?php echo $percentage."%" ?></div>
            <?php 
            } 
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php 
    } 
}
else
{
    echo "No skills found";
}
?>
```